# Show that C(R) dense in R^R

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, function-spaces

Let $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$ be the set of function from $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $C(\mathbb{R})$ the subspace of continuous functions. I want to show that $C(R)$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$.

I think we can do something like this. Since $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$ has product topology, if $U = \prod U_\alpha$ is a neighborhood of $f$ then finitely many $U_\alpha$ are not $\mathbb{R}$. There must be therefore be $U_i = \mathbb{R}$ between $U_\alpha \neq \mathbb{R}$'s where this is not true. Then somehow we should choose $g(x_i) \in U_i$ to make the $g \in U$ continuous (i.e. we have free range over $g$ for the $U_i = \mathbb{R}$)?

Is it then true that for all $f$ there is some sequence of continuous functions $\{f_n\}$ that converge to $f$ pointwise?

Am I on the right track? Can anyone help me formalize this argument? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that there's no need to think about sequences of functions. You just need to show that in your arbitrary open set $U$, there is some continuous function $g$.

Barring that, if I understand you, it seems to me like you're on the right track; to show density, you need only find a continuous function $g:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ in your open set $U$, i.e. such that $g(x_i) \in U_i$ for each $i$. Since there are only finitely many $x_i$ to worry about, this is definitely possible. Just pick a point $y_i\in U_i$ for each $i$ and find a continuous $g$ such that $g(x_i) = y_i$. You are correct in saying you have free range to set the values of $g$ to be whatever you want away from the $x_i$, so you have many options for $g$. You could pick $g$ to be a polynomial, for instance, or piecewise linear.